# Jackson JSON: What is the difference between withArray and putArray

Tags: java, json, jackson

While updating the JSON using JACKSON databind, I found two method to add values in "withArray" and "putArray" but I dont found any difference between it. Could someone please clarify the difference between both methods.

```
 ((ObjectNode)root).withArray("withArray").add("withArray1").add("WithArray2");
 ((ObjectNode)root).putArray("putArray").add("putArray").add("PutArray2");
```

Sample output:
"withArray" : [ "withArray1", "WithArray2" ],
"putArray" : [ "putArray", "PutArray2" ]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/index-all.html

Comment: Please make an effort to research your question (and even attempt to write the code your suggesting) before posting.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like both method eventually do the same thing which is insert an ArrayNode to the provided node except,

1. `withArray` would check if the 'withArray' child exists and is of type `ArrayNode` . If yes it would return the existing value but `putArray` would override it.
2. `withArray` would throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if the child node with the `withArray` exists and is of not type `ArrayNode`. But `putArray` would override it anyway.
3. `withArray` method would only add the child node if the child is not present.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!!

Comment: please consider upvoting and accepting the answer @AjeetYadawa